# Distinct in join query with linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I got 3 rows with same CommentingAuthor, how i do distinct to get 1 CommentingAuthor???

```
 IEnumerable<CommentingAuthor> CommentingAuthor =
                        from p in db.Posts
                        join c in db.Comments on p.WebSite equals c.CommentWebSite
                        select new CommentingAuthor
                        {
                            PostAuthorName = p.PostAuthor,
                            AuthorProfilePicture = c.CommentWebSite
                        };            

            return View(CommentingAuthor);
```

Comment: `CommentingAuthor.Distinct()` should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Distinct`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb338049(v=vs.100).aspx).  You may have to implement your own custom comparer.

```
var uniqueCommentingAuthors = CommentingAuthor.Distinct();
```

Using a customer comparer:

```
public class CommentingAuthorComparer : IEqualityComparer<CommentingAuthor>
{
    public bool Equals(CommentingAuthor author, CommentingAuthor author2)
    {
        return author.PostAuthorName.Equals(author2.PostAuthorName);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(CommentingAuthor author)
    {
        return author.PostAuthorName.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then you can use it like:

```
   var comparer = new CommentingAuthorComparer();
   var uniqueAuthors = CommentingAuthor.Distinct(comparer);
   return View(uniqueAuthors);
```

Comment: i tryed it but it is showing the same, i return uniqueCommentingAuthors right?